# How to set Microsoft Test Manager record sensitivity?

Tags: .net, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

In Microsoft Test Manager I am creating an automation recording for a CodedUI test.  It seems to be picking up hover events that are not relevant to the test itself.  Is there any way to configure test manager to only record actual text input and button clicks?  I don't care about hover events.

Thanks.

Comment: Open Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio xx.0\Common7\IDE\mtm.exe.config. In <add key="RecordImplicitHover" value="true"/> change "true" to "false".

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the CodedUI Test recorder provided with Microsoft's coded ui test framework, you can expand the actions pane on the recorder and delete the events you don't want in the recording. If it's too late for that, you can examine the code in the designer class created for the recording and remove the lines regarding the hover events you're talking about. Keep in mind this is a bit more complicated since it's generated code, so if you have the option to delete them before you create your method, I would do it that way.

Edit:

Furthermore, and I hadn't mentioned this before, but if you change anything in the generated code and then regenerate your recording, any of your changes will be overwritten. You can do something silly like copy your recording method from the generated code over to the partial class (which does not regenerate) and make your changes there.

Comment: You can also delete the hover actions in the UI Map editor, so no need to edit the actual C# code.